# javascript getElementsByClassName from javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting some html from a angular get request and I'm trying to get some specific elements from this response. Which is a list of div's with the class "post-holder". Extracting the html works fine, but to extract each div to insert separately has some troubles.

This is the code I'm trying with:

```
var firstTag = '<main id="posts">';
var res = data.substring(data.indexOf(firstTag) + firstTag.length, data.indexOf('</main>'));
var html2 = $.parseHTML( res );
var x = html2.getElementsByClassName("post-holder");
```

The last line gives me the following error in chrome: "TypeError: undefined is not a function".

I'm guessing that **getElementsByClass** has some troubles with the variable generated by jquery. Is there another approach to do the same or a way to fix what I already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation for parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/):

> Returns: Array
>
> Description: Parses a string into an array of DOM nodes.

`getElementsByClassName` is a method on DOM elements, not on arrays. You need to loop over the array, check if each value is an element (as opposed to, for instance, a text node or a comment) and then call `getElementsByClassName` on the values.

Or you could just construct a jQuery object and use `.find()` on it instead.